# Java Web Server

Tags: java, networking, web

I am trying to build my simple webserver in java. So I found this code in tutorial
I was trying to understand what does this method do but I could not any one can explain 
what is the use of BufferedReader and why he used it.

```
public void run()
{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            String line = reader.readLine();
            String filename = "";
            File file = null;

            String parts[] = line.split(" ");

            if (parts.length != 3)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (parts[0].compareTo("GET") == 0)
            {
                filename = parts[1].substring(1);

                if (filename.equals("favicon.ico") == true)
                {
                    System.out.println("404 File Not Found!");
                    return;
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.println(filename);
                }
            }


            printToBrowser(bos, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            printToBrowser(bos, "");

            if (filename.compareTo("") == 0)
            {
                file = new File("index.txt");
            }

            else
            {
                file = new File(filename);
            }

            try
            {   
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                int a; 
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                while ((a = input.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                {   
                    sleep(100);
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, a);
                }   
                    }
            }
```

Comment: Side note: In `if (filename.equals("favicon.ico") == true)`, There is no need for the `== true`. `if (filename.equals("favicon.ico"))` is enough (and better).

Comment: @maroun-maroun i agree but better is debatable. i know some other wise productive programmers who just love to add the true part and hate !xBoolVar, prefer xBoolVar == false. See http://www.quickserver.org/ code for sample

Comment: Is your main question ' was trying to understand what does this method do ' ? This is the heart of the web server response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the code and rewritten it a little and added more comment, hope this helps

```
public void run()
{
           //Create a reader to read the request from client
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

           //from client get the line
            String line = reader.readLine();

            //file name client sends or use default one
            String filename = "";

            //file to read
            File file = null;

           //split the request with (space) as separator
            String parts[] = line.split(" ");

           // if we don't have exactly 3 words, return
            if (parts.length != 3) {
                return;
            }

           // if first part is GET
            if (parts[0].compareTo("GET") == 0) {
                //second word is the file name
                filename = parts[1].substring(1);

                //if filename is favicon.ico then print 404 not found
                if (filename.equals("favicon.ico")) {
                    System.out.println("404 File Not Found!");
                    return;
                } else {
                    //else print the file name
                    System.out.println(filename);
                }
            }

           //tell the requiting client the request was successful
            printToBrowser(bos, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            //i think this is to indicate end of line
            printToBrowser(bos, "");

            if (filename.equals("")) { 
                file = new File("index.txt"); //if there is no file name set the file to index.txt
            } else {
                file = new File(filename); //else of the file name
            }

            try {   
                FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file); //read the file
                int a; 
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //create a buffer of 1024 bytes could also use BufferedReader

                while ((a = input.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) { //read the file   
                    sleep(100); //sleep, not sure why this is here
                    bos.write(buffer, 0, a); //send the file to client
                }   

            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO : handle the error more gracefully, also indicate to client
                System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
           }
```

Comment: he also add this method can you please explain to me what is doing  private void printToBrowser(BufferedOutputStream bos, String s)   
 {
  try
   {
     String news = s + "\r\n";
     byte[] array = news.getBytes();

     for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++)
       bos.write(array[i]);

     return;
  }

  catch(Exception e)
  {
   System.err.println(e);
  }
 }

Comment: this method is returning the given string "s" to the client

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.

If you are asking about the BufferedReader class in general, you should start with the [class reference doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), Oracle's [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html), and a little [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20BufferedReader&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 0):

Here BufferedReader is used to read request from the client side. You question is why BufferedReader?

Advantage of `BufferedReader` is: It is fast and allows us to read whole line instead of character, means it iterates over line. If in case BufferedReader is not used than we have to write extra code to create a string by concatenating characters then split it to proccess further, which is time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Buffered reader is reading the request. It buffers it for performance. You should read up on  the HTTP protocol - how the first line indicates the operation type, what the header is, important headers, body, how a web form values are sent in a request etc.

- This method is parsing the request and responding to it.
- For some reason he does not support a favicon so responds with a not found without checking of there is one. This is not a full featured web server

See 
* http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/
* http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/ 
* http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

- Most web servers are written in C++ but you could have one in Java for a node that gets a few 100 hits an hour.